# Being schema or schemaless in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, schemaless

I like the schemaless architecture of Mongodb. That makes it so flexible. Yet there's certain requirements like model relationship and data validation that is needed which Mongoose ODM provides.

I've read a handful of SO threads where I found that Mongoose's performance in handling really complex document structure is not that good comparative to the native MongoDB driver, in my case NodeJS driver.

I dont want to loose the being-schemaless flexibility which makes it really great to change my structure whenever I want. But I want to use the model relationship.

Which practice is better : schemaless or using schema particularly in Mongo?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to avoid some of the overhead that mongoose provides and a way to get access to native mongoDb commands for the NodeJs driver in your script.

You are able to get access to The [mongodb.Db instance](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-db).

because of that you can get access to the [db constructor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) for the Nodejs driver.

So I could do stuff like this in my node js/ mongoose file

```
mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection("collectionName", function(err, doc){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(doc);
})
```

Also if you don't want the overhead that mongoose provides with the extra properties on the object that is returned from queries you can use `.lean()`. If you use `lean` you get back plain javascript objects and not mongoose documents. Lean is much faster.

EXAMPLE::

```
Model.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
  docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```